# Download many check images from Wells Fargo?

Tags: online-banking

How can one download a year's worth of check images for a Wells Fargo checking account?

https://www.wellsfargo.com/biz/help/faqs/check-images/ describes a poor option of "go to Account Activity. Click the check icon next to the check you would like to see."  This will be onerous for a full year's worth of checks.

Comment: Onerous? I've probably only written 2 checks last year - I was aiming for none, but some people haven't quite gotten themselves into the 21st century yet...

Comment: @brhans even with web bill pay, there might be a "lot" of checks.

Comment: During my divorce, I had to manually download two year's worth of statements for a half-dozen accounts.  It was definitely onerous drudge work made even worse by having to remember to name them all correctly.  This is the cost you pay for pretty GUIs.